# Custom WordPress Email not sending to BCC issue

Tags: wordpress, email

Edit: Installed SMTP plugin and it works fine.

I have a couple of custom emails setup for my WordPress website. One of which should send an email to a posts author and a copy to the website admin. The admin email is not being sent out.
Please can someone let me know what the issue could be.

Thanks

```
// Send out email after post expires
                        $to = $author_email;
                        $subject  = 'Your Listing has expired.';
                        $message  = '<p>Hello ' . $author_display_name . '.</p><p>Please <a title="Your Account" target="_blank" href="'. esc_url( get_permalink( $page_id_dashboard ) ) .'">log into your account here</a> to renew your listing for: <strong>' . get_the_title($post_id) . '</strong>, today!</p>';
                        
                        $headers = 'Bcc: '.$admin_sitename.' <'.$admin_email.'>';
                        $mail = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
                        wp_update_post($postdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

Installed and setup a SMTP plugin which solved my issue.